# Horizontally center search bar bootstrap nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to center the search bar in my navbar. I am using bootstrap, I tried text-center on the md-4 but it had no effect.

Here is a link to my code.

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/50b38

Comment: Use the bootstrap class ["text-center"](http://getbootstrap.com/css?#type-alignment) on col-md-8

Comment: @pocockn, It has been a few days. Did my answer help?

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap uses a grid of 12 columns.  Your code had the first column be 8 and the 2nd one be 4.  This would mean that your first column would be 2/3 of the page.  By making it col-md-4, it allows your middle div to be center.

```
  <div class="row top-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=30&txt=320%C3%97240&w=235&h=126" alt="logo image" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="search-center">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is an updated source:
http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/E7WgX

Answer (score -1):

over your code in css tag, i put that and seems ork

```
.top-header {
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Expect it help you

Comment: could be, but it was testted before in his url